# How to use a prop in computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a carousel component that receives a prop 'mediaItems' and I use that prop in a computed property to determine the end of the carousel:

```
props: ['mediaItems', 'sliderHeading'],
computed: {
  atEndOfList() {
    return this.currentOffset <= (this.paginationFactor * -1) * (this.mediaItems.length / this.windowSize) + this.paginationFactor;
},
```

This results in an empty component and I get a console error that says:

> TypeError: this.mediaItems is undefined

If I remove the computed property, the component loads with props and I don't get console error but I need this computed property to determine the end of the carousel.

Comment: just check its defined before doing `.length`, when it gets populated atEndOfList will be recomputed

Comment: Check for misspelled usage, your props is `mediaItems` and the error you presented is `mediaItem`

Comment: @Giovane oops, that was a typo in my console error above. thanks

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how do you check if prop is defined in computed property? Like if(this.mediaItems.length)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should indicate a default value for this prop in order to make a computed prop to work properly while `mediaItems` prop is not set yet outside:

```
props: {
  mediaItems: {
    type: Array,
    default: ()=>[]
  }, 
  sliderHeading: String
}
```

Comment: The default value should be a function:  default: ()=>[]

Comment: Yes this solution with the function as default value works! Thanks Anatoly